# jQuery UI .buttonset() is too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jquery-ui

I have a few thousand buttons on an HTML page. It takes more than 10 seconds to run `$(".buttonset").buttonset();` on document ready. Is there a faster way to do this, or is my only solution to somehow limit the number of buttons?

Comment: I think you already know the answer to this one.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, would you mind telling us why you would need that many buttons on one page?

Comment: I do operations on thousands of jquery objects that run faster. What's in your buttonset function ?

Comment: @dystroy: he's talking about the `buttonset()` jQuery UI method, I believe.  OP, I think this is the sort of situation where making a custom solution starts to become preferable.  Either that or reduce the number of buttons as others have suggested.

Comment: I have a giant set of things to display, each of which fits into a specific category. There are a few thousand categories. I'd like the user to be able to filter which categories they look at.

Comment: A trick I sometimes use is splitting the operations to do one second later (for example) what doesn't really have to be done instantly (like hooking bubbles on items that aren't visible due to scroll position).

Comment: Thousands of buttons in a single webpage? I'd use pagination. Now as you have some kind of filtering, I'd create the buttonsets on demand when a group is about to be shown.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: yea the thousands of buttons actually fit into a dozen categories or so, ill make +/- menus and load on demand as you said, i think that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `buttonset`s on demand before they are shown by the first time.

I just tested with 2400 boxes split in 12 sections. It runs smoothly on my i7 using Chrome 23, Firefox 17, IE9, Opera 12.

This may add a split loading moment for the first time you open a a checkbox group, but it does save some RAM by not creating unused styled buttons until they're necessary.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MyYV4/1/)

Comment: I think this is the solution.  You could also build the HTML of the buttonsets to match what jquery-ui will eventually produce, then on click run `buttonset`, and refire click.

Comment: Of course, I'm not meaning everything, simply the created `<span>` wrappers and whatnot that jquery-ui inserts so the buttons could be styled through jquery-ui's stylesheets before actually becoming widgets.

Comment: Oh yes the span inside the label, I'll take a look on that. `=]`

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a similar HTML structure than the one produced by the UI: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MyYV4/5/). I didn't notice much of a difference in performance except by the initial overhead when creating them, I guess the UI handles it better. `:P` Otherwise making a custom plugin would be the best optimization-wise.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much you can do about the speed that `buttonset()` takes to setup the thousands of buttons, but if your problem with the 10 seconds is a browser message saying that the page has become unresponsive you can break up the operation into asynchronous operations with a setTimeout call.

```
$(".buttonset").buttonset();
```

Would become:

```
$(".buttonset").each(function(index, button) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $(button).buttonset();
   }, 0);
});
```

I've used this pattern successfully with thousands of jQuery UI objects, and while it doesn't speed up the operation it will keep the page from locking up, thus giving the appearance that it is working faster.

Comment: Still shows a browser unresponsive message [for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MyYV4/2/) on IE9 and freezes up Firefox, and it takes longer to process with the timeouts than without, but if it works..