# why is my context selector and .buttonset() taking so long in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

So I assume this is something I'm doing flagrantly wrong. It is soo slow in ie there must be something fundamentally wrong with this.

Le HTML

```
<div id='mother'>

  <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
      <label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" />
      <label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
  </div>

  <div id="radioTwa">
    <input type="radio" id="radioTwa1" name="radioTwa" />
      <label for="radioTwa1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioTwa2" name="radioTwa" checked="checked" />
      <label for="radioTwa2">Choice 2</label>

  </div>

  <div id="check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check" />
      <label for="check1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check" checked="checked" />
      <label for="check2">Choice 2</label>

  </div>

</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Le JQuery/JQuery UI

```
    var mother = $('​​​​​​​​​​​​​​#mother');
​    mother.find('#radio').buttonset();​​​​​​
    mother.find('#radioTwa').buttonset();
    mother.find('#check').buttonset();
```

or

```
    var mother = $(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​'#mother');
​    $('#radio', mother).buttonset();​​​​​​
    $('#radioTwa', mother).buttonset();
    $('#check', mother).buttonset();
```

Both of these will bring IE 8 to it's knees and make it cry. To nip some things in the bud I am using the context of mother on purpose. I do not have a unique ID to each radio box, I planned to select them using context, because of the number 'mother' type divs that are on the page though each mother div element I am using only has about 8 or 9 elements within it. Is there no way to select using context in IE 8 that is quick enough to not grind it to a halt?

Comment: There's no need for a context or .find() when using ID selectors.  The fastest is always doing just `$('#radio')`.  Not sure why buttonset() is so slow though...

Comment: Well thanks Nal, I know I don't have to use the context selector with the example I provided, but with the code I am working on, it is how it is set up and to change it would be a considerable amount of work. As you pointed out though, the .buttonset() is what is really causing the issue.

Comment: How many buttons do you have total? There seems to be a few compliants about slow buttonssets on stackoverlow.  Also I found http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5454

Comment: Short answer 60-120 on page. In any given radio or check there are only 2 buttons, in any given 'mother' div there is 6 buttons, 4 input:radio 2 input:check. There is also a input:text within a 'mother' div. there are 10-20 'mother' divs depending on content. So I think that bug might be what I am running into. I fixed another error in my code and now it's not so slow that it causes the page to halt, but still a little bit of crying.

Comment: Hrm, that's not a huge huge amount but still a lot. This solution might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060742/jquery-ui-buttonset-is-too-slow

Comment: Um I am only binding them when they are about to show. So I believe it is just the bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5454 that you posted. If you post that as an answer I'm prepared to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many buttons do you have total? There seems to be a few compliants about slow buttonssets on stackoverlow. Also I found bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5454 – Nal

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the bug that Nal links too.